# value for all row is not getting added in a column if it has same value in the column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to the `python and pandas.` here I have a `xlsx` file created and now, when I am trying to save the file that time first column is having the same values in the column. But still, it is not getting added in the `xlsx file` .

```
Document_Id     error
   0             1 
                 1 
                 0
                 1
```

It should have been like this ,

```
Document_Id     error
       0              1 
       0              1 
       0              0
       -              1
```

Now, I tried ,

```
pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False)
file_name = file_name.replace(".csv", ".xlsx")
  output_df.to_excel("check_one.xlsx");
```

But still not working ? can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: please check the code which I have updated.

Comment: What is returned if you assert    output_df.to_numpy() ?

Comment: Also, try set_option() instead of option_context(). Or open a with statement to use option_context()

Comment: [[1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]

It returns this value

Comment: Please share **all** relevant code and data. See: [mcve]. As it stands we have very little in the way of explanations, and certainly not enough to run the program in any capacity.